# C# Selenium , SystemNull Reference Exception

Tags: c#, selenium

When i run this code i am receiving an error as "Object reference not set to instance of object " its able to click on the first element "Services" but unable to print the text or the a href link. a href link text is "Services"

```
    public void TestSetUp()
    {
        // the same way we can setup webDriver to use other browsers
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // set the timeout after page load to 30seconds
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));

    }


    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.prokarma.com/");

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20));

        IWebElement hover1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath ( "//*[@id='oe_menu']" ));
        IList<IWebElement> subelements = hover1.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
        System.Console.WriteLine("Number of elements under li tag are :-->" + subelements.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < subelements.Count; i++)
        {
            subelements[i].Click();
            string mesage = subelements[i].GetAttribute("a href").ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Value from textbox is: " + mesage);

        }   

    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void FixtureTearDown()
    {

        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 33 li tags are there , under each li ,  a href texts are services etc etc , i am not able to print the text "Services " under the li tag.

Answer (score 2):

To get your link from href you need to ask for attribute "href" not "a href":

```
  string mesage = subelements[i].GetAttribute("href");
```

Comment: @user3065782, then you should accept this as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your null pointer is comming because th4e below value is returning null. Your syntax is wrong here

```
subelements[i].GetAttribute("a href")
```

You need to change this line to and then it should work

```
subelements[i].GetAttribute("href")
```